# Multiple ethernet interface on one ethernet card

Tags: linux, linux-networking, kernel, ethernet, kernel-modules

First I must say that I am new in linux and maybe I will ask trivial question.
My job is to create 8 ethernet interface to be visible in kernel, but all of them should send and receive data through only one real ethernet interface. All of that 8 interfaces should to can be configured with ifconfig (or some one similar command).
Does anyone have idea how to do this? It was told to me to change something in ethernet driver, but i dont know what? Or is there some other solution?

Comment: What OS are you running? The config files differ a bit, as do the commands, but basically you will be creating eth0:0 eth0:1 eth0:2 and so forth..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up virtual interfaces by appending to the physical interface name `:<n>` where `n` is a number.

```
$ ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Using the `ip` utility, you can even specify a name:

```
$ ip link add link eth0 name virt1
$ ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev virt1
```